# How to create a war in a specific location based on condition in ANT?

Tags: ant, conditional-statements, war

In my ANT script - there is a input parameter 'global'.

If global=true 
then mkdir 'a' and create war at 'a'
else if global=false
then mkdir 'b' and create war at 'b'

Is there any way in ANT to achieve this?

Comment: Do you use ant-contrib?  It has an [<if> task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html) that would make this pretty simple.

Comment: No. I don't use ant-contrib. Is there any way to achieve this with plain ANT?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible with plain Ant using the `<condition>` task.  I have an answer to offer but for some reason stack overflow is giving me an error right now when I try to submit.  I pasted it here instead: http://pastebin.com/0hLKAD9v

Comment: @CAustin, Thank you! one related question. what if the directory to be created is to be obtained from another property?

<condition property="war.dir" value="a" else="b">
        <equals arg1="${global}" arg2="true" />
    </condition>

Comment: In that case you could just do something like `<condition property="war.dir" value="${property.a}" else="${property.b}">` if I'm understanding the problem correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ways...

You can use the condition task:

```
<condition
     property="war.dir"
     value="a"
     else="b">
    <istrue arg1="${global}"/>
</condition>
```

You might be able to use the new [if and unless](http://ant.apache.org/manual/ifunless.html) in a `<property/>` task. I've had problems with these.